# Configure the window of an NSWindowController before it appears on screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I am using an `NSWindowController` not I want to set some attributes (specifically the `styleMask` property) on the window, before the actual window is shown. However, the `window` property on the `NSWindowController` is only available once the window is already on screen.

I could use `initWithWindow:` on the `NSWindowController` but then I am no longer able to use a nib file for the content of the window (because this uses `initWithWindowNibName:`.

So how can I configure the view before it is shown, something similar to `viewWillAppear` on `NSView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Interface Builder, uncheck the ‘Visible At Launch’ attribute. When doing this, the window is not shown when the corresponding nib file is loaded by the window controller, so you can configure your window in `-[NSWindowController windowDidLoad]` and then manually show it using  `-[NSWindowController showWindow:]`.

<sup>Note that there’s no `-viewWillAppear` method in Cocoa.</sup>